# Turtle raise terminator error when switching code editors

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I made a code using replit.com for a bow and arrow minigame, and it worked like a charm. However, when I imported the code to VSC using python 3.9.6, I get some errors that I don't have on replit.

My code is:

```
import math
import turtle
import time

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Tiro al blanco")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width = 800, height = 600)
wn.tracer(0)

#parametros optimos: vi = 14.5, th = 45

vi = 14.5
th = 45

segs = 0
score = 0


#dibujar target
target = turtle.Turtle()
target.speed(0) #Velocidad de animacion, no de movimiento
target.shape("circle")
target.color("white")
target.shapesize(stretch_wid = 3, stretch_len = 3) 
target.penup() ##Para que no trace línea de movimiento
target.goto(350,0) ##posición inicial

target2 = turtle.Turtle()
target2.speed(0) #Velocidad de animacion, no de movimiento
target2.shape("circle")
target2.color("red")
target2.shapesize(stretch_wid = 2, stretch_len = 2) 
target2.penup() ##Para que no trace línea de movimiento
target2.goto(350,0) ##posición inicial

target3 = turtle.Turtle()
target3.speed(0) #Velocidad de animacion, no de movimiento
target3.shape("circle")
target3.color("white")
target3.shapesize(stretch_wid = 1, stretch_len = 1) 
target3.penup() ##Para que no trace línea de movimiento
target3.goto(350,0) ##posición inicial

target4 = turtle.Turtle()
target4.speed(0) #Velocidad de animacion, no de movimiento
target4.shape("circle")
target4.color("red")
target4.shapesize(stretch_wid = 0.5, stretch_len = 0.5) 
target4.penup() ##Para que no trace línea de movimiento
target4.goto(350,0) ##posición inicial


#dibujar arco
bow = turtle.Turtle()
bow.speed(0) #Velocidad de animacion, no de movimiento
bow.shape(turtle.circle(20,180))
bow.color("brown")
bow.shapesize(stretch_wid = 5, stretch_len = 1) 
bow.penup() ##Para que no trace línea de movimiento
bow.goto(-350,0) ##posición inicial


#dibujar flecha
arrow = turtle.Turtle()
arrow.speed(0) #Velocidad de animacion, no de movimiento
arrow.shape("arrow")
arrow.color("cyan")
arrow.penup() ##Para que no trace línea de movimiento
arrow.goto(-350,0) ##posición inicial

arrow.velx = vi*math.cos(math.radians(th))

arrow.vely = vi*math.sin(math.radians(th))


#scoreboard
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 260)
pen.write("Score: 0", align = "center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

#parametros
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, -260)
pen.write("Velocidad:{}, Inclinacion: {} ".format(vi, th), align = "center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))



while True:
  wn.update()

  segs +=1 

  arrow.vely = vi*math.sin(math.radians(th)) - 0.3*(segs)
  
  if arrow.ycor() < -100:
   arrow.vely = 0
   arrow.velx = 0

  if arrow.ycor() > 275:
    arrow.vely = 0
    arrow.velx = 0
    

  if arrow.xcor() > 335:
    arrow.vely = 0
    arrow.velx = 0

  
  if arrow.xcor() >= 330:
    if arrow.xcor() <= 350:
      if arrow.ycor() >= -30:
        if arrow.ycor() <= 30:
          arrow.vely = 0
          arrow.velx = 0
          score +=1
          pen.clear()
          
          time.sleep(3)
          arrow.goto(-350,0)
          
           
  arrow.setx(arrow.xcor() + arrow.velx)
  arrow.sety(arrow.ycor() + arrow.vely)
```

And I get the error mesages:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nicolasderbez/Desktop/tiroalblanco.py", line 21, in <module>
    target = turtle.Turtle()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 3814, in __init__
    RawTurtle.__init__(self, Turtle._screen,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 2558, in __init__
    self._update()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 2661, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 2647, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 1293, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator
```

As mentioned, I don't get any error messages on replit. Is it possible that the versions are different and I have to write my code again?

Comment: This works OK for me other than the `while True: wn.update()` running too fast. Better to use `ontimer` for a fairly consistent event loop. I also suggest using lists rather than `thing1`, `thing2`... and 4 space indentation. You can use `and` rather than nested `if`s to reduce cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: @ggorlen when you say it works okay for you, do you mean you can run it with no errors on your machine? if so, where are you running it?

Comment: No errors, ran on Ubuntu 22.04, py 3.11.

Comment: @ggorlen This worked! I updated from 3.9 to 3.11 and it run with no problems. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an update to a newer Python version the code runs without problems.

Try also:

```
vi = 15.7
th = 30
```

and add time.sleep() to make the arrow path visible also on fast machines.

```
while True:
  wn.update()
  time.sleep(0.1)
```